# Setting log scale on colorbar in matplotlib raises Value error, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, normalization

I am plotting an xarray dataset with a colorbar which I want in log, I tried to use the following code -

```
from cdasws import CdasWs
from cdasws.datarepresentation import DataRepresentation
cdas = CdasWs()
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stereo_dataset = wind_dataset = cdas.get_datasets(observatoryGroup='STEREO')

stereo_data = cdas.get_data('STEREO_LEVEL2_SWAVES', ['avg_intens_ahead'],
                     '2020-07-11T02:15:00Z', '2020-07-11T02:50:00Z',
                     dataRepresentation = DataRepresentation.XARRAY)[1]
# stereo_data
sorted_data = stereo_data.avg_intens_ahead.sortby('frequency')

sorted_data.transpose().plot.pcolormesh(ax=ax3, cbar_kwargs={"label":"STEREO-A"}, norm=colors.LogNorm())
```

I get the following errors `ValueError: Invalid vmin or vmax` and `AttributeError: 'Colorbar' object has no attribute '_boundaries'`. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Does your data contain zeros or negative values? If so, the `LogNorm` is not going to like them (it takes the log _before_ normalising the range between 0 and 1). You could try using [`SymLogNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm.html) instead.

Comment: @MattPitkin thanks! using `SymLogNorm` did help but I am a little unclear as to what linthresh means and what value I should set for it?

Comment: The `SymLogNorm` combines a normal logarithmic part, a linear part around zero, and an inverted logarithmic part for negative values.  `linthresh` is the data value at which the scaling switches between logarithmic and linear.  It should be set to the smallest positive value you want to see on your logarithmic scale. An alternative is to set the ylim of the colorbar to a value slightly above zero and then use a normal logscale.

Comment: You probably want to do `norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1e-5)` or whatever low positive value you need.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned above you have probably 0 values in your data.

Setting vmin in the xarray function call is the easiest/fastest way to solve that.

```
.pcolormesh(ax=ax, norm=colors.LogNorm(), vmin=1e-1)
```